# Ruby || Routing Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having a routing issue with my app.

When I even try to view the page I get the following error

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Conferences#index
No route matches {:action=>"create", :conference_id=>nil, :controller=>"subscriptions", :format=>nil} missing required keys: [:conference_id]
```

The cause of the problem is a missing required key. I've got no clue what the missing key is and how i can find it.

I believe there is something wrong with the way the form is setup, but I don't know what.

Can someone tell me, what the cause of the routing issue is? And maybe even tell me how to solve it?

**Routes.rb**

```
  resources :conferences, shallow: true do
    resources :subscriptions, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
  <% @conferences.each do |conference| %>
  <div class="box">
    <%= image_tag conference.picture.url, :class => "background"  if conference.picture?%>
    <div class="text-box">
      <p>CONFERENCE:<%= conference.conference %>
      </p>
      <p>COUNTRY:<%= conference.country %>
      </p>
      <p>MONTH:<%= conference.month %>
      </p>
      <p>PRESENCE:<%= conference.presence %>
      </p>
      <p>AUDIENCE:<%= conference.audience %>
      </p>
      <p>COST:<%= conference.cost %>
      </p>
      <p>Attending:
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% if current_user.subscribed_to?(@conference) %>
  <%= button_to "Unsubscribe", subscription_path(current_user.find_subscription(@conference)), method: :delete %>

<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Subscribe", conference_subscriptions_path(@conference, @subscription), method: :post %>
<% end %>

  <% end %>
```

**ConferenceController**

```
   def index
      @conferences = Conference.paginate(page: params[:page])


      if params[:search]
        @conferences = Conference.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC").paginate(page: params[:page])
      else
        @conferences = Conference.all.order('created_at DESC').paginate(page: params[:page])
      end
    end
```

**SubscriptionController**

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_conference, only: :create

  def create
    if current_user.subsciptions.create(conference: @conference)
      flash[:success] = "You are now subscribed to { @conference.name }"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Could not create subscription."
    end
    redirect_to @conference
  end

  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subsciptions.find(params[:id])
    if @subscription.destroy
      flash[:success] = "You are no longer subscribed to { @conference.name }"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Oh noes"
    end

    redirect_to @subscription.conference
  end

  def set_conference
    @conference = Conference.find(:params[conference_id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You iterate though `@conferences` like this

```
<% @conferences.each do |conference| %>
```

Therefore in each iteration there is a local variable `conference`, but not instance variable `@conference`. Just change the button section to:

```
<% if current_user.subscribed_to?(conference) %>
  <%= button_to "Unsubscribe", 
                subscription_path(current_user.find_subscription(conference)), 
                method: :delete %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to "Subscribe", 
                conference_subscriptions_path(conference), 
                method: :post %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still pretty new to Ruby :)